How to force generation of Image thumbnails?
If you load an image into Blender, its thumbnail preview is not automatically generated until you, for example, open the "Browse image to be linked" menu of an Image Texture node at which point you can see the thumbnails appear one after the other as they are generated.
How can I force this preview thumbnail generation so that they are available via
img.preview.icon_id


We can force Blender to generate preview thumbnails for loaded images with this:
img.preview_ensure()

